# ListView with lots of items has problems with painting

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-4.0, paint

I'm populating a couple of Windows Forms `ListView` controls with hundreds of items but when I go to resize the columns, the `ListView` has a lot of stuttering while redrawing the content.

I understand that some stuttering will happen as the columns get resized, but the desired effect would be equivalent to how Windows Explorer handles column resizing when in details view. It appears that when a column is resized in Windows Explorer, it only slightly stutters the columns to the right of the column being resized.

Is there a way to prevent or reduce the stuttering or is this expected behavior?

Comment: Are they `custom listViews` or just standard ones?

Comment: They are standard `ListView` controls.

Comment: How many columns do they have? Well, I think the default `ListView` can help you display fairly well everything. It's just not skinny. BTW, I think the `ListView` used in `Windows Explorer` may be different than the `ListView` in `Winforms`, it may be some `WPF ListView` depending on the version of Windows.

Comment: You can also try enabling `DoubleBuffered` by this code `typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(yourListView, true, null);`

Comment: They have 4 and 6 columns. Good point about Windows Explorer possibly using WPF ListView. I may need to use a beefier ListView control if I want to get better painting on column resize.

Comment: Enabling DoubleBuffered did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: @KingKing Windows is not managed, it doesn't use any .Net components. for WinDiv, .Net is the enemy. It's all political, rather than technical. No Windows doesn't have any WPF components, nor winforms, they use something called DirectUI, which is C++ DirectX hardcore stuff.

Comment: @HighCore nice to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by King King, enabling double buffering on the control fixed the problem:

```
 typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
 BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(yourListView, true, null);
```